# Scale and Transition image from bottom center to center of the screen

Tags: android, animation, scale

I want to scale image from bottom center to center of the screen. This is my animation xml, image scales from just above top left of the center to center of the screen. Please help me to understand what is wrong here.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator" >



    <translate
        android:duration="750"
       android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" 
        android:fromXDelta="0%"
        android:toXDelta="0%" />

        <scale
            android:duration="500"
            android:fromXScale="0.1"
            android:fromYScale="0.1"
            android:pivotX="0.5"
            android:pivotY="0.5"
            android:toXScale="1"
            android:toYScale="1" 
            android:fillBefore="false" />

</set>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void moveViewToScreenCenter( final View view ){
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( dm );

        int originalPos[] = new int[2];
        view.getLocationOnScreen( originalPos );

        int xDelta = (dm.widthPixels - view.getMeasuredWidth() - originalPos[0])/2;
        int yDelta = (dm.heightPixels - view.getMeasuredHeight() - originalPos[1])/2;

        AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSet.setFillAfter(true);
        animSet.setDuration(1000);
        animSet.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
        TranslateAnimation translate = new TranslateAnimation( 0, xDelta , 0, yDelta);
        animSet.addAnimation(translate);
        ScaleAnimation scale = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 2f, 1f, 2f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f, ScaleAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, .5f);
        animSet.addAnimation(scale);
        view.startAnimation(animSet);
    }
```